# How do I use cmake to ensure a C++14 compiler links with the experimental filesystem TS library?

Tags: c++, cmake, c++14, std-filesystem

I'm (switching to) using `<std::experimental::filesystem>` in my C++14 code, and I need to be able to build it using GCC 5.x on Linux (and any C++14-enabled compiler really, or at least - relevant versions of clang, msvc and perhaps icc) .

Now, when I link, I'm getting errors about missing all of the filesystem-related symbols, e.g.:

```
foo.cpp:(.text+0x9cd): undefined reference to `std::experimental::filesystem::v1::__cxx11::path::_M_split_cmpts()'
```

Now, if I "manually" add a dependency on `libstdc++fs`:

```
target_link_libraries(foo other_lib stdc++fs)
```

then everything links fine - but how do I generalize this to any C++14-capable compiler?

Note: The relevant parts of my `CMakeLists.txt` look something like this:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall" )
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_library(bar src/bar.cpp)
add_executable(foo src/foo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo bar other_lib)
```

---

<sub>*
(When I was using `boost::filesystem` it was paradoxically easier - I just need to use whatever `FindBoost.cmake` produced.)

** Using `-Wall` is a problem for other compilers as well, I guess.</sub>

Comment: Please, post the full CMakeLists.txt. Specifically, how do you enable C++14?

Comment: @lisyarus: See edit.

Comment: `std::experimental::filesystem` is a C++17 TS and `std::filesystem` is a C++17 feature. You should upgrade to a more recent compiler, which supports C++17 and thus `std::filesystem` out of the box. GCC 8.0, which was released a few days ago, now has proper support for `std::filesystem`.

Comment: @tambre: There is no "upgrade", it's a library I will be distributing, and I can't rely on C++17 support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is exactly how it is intended to be used. See [the relevant part of libstdc++ documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.experimental):

> GCC 5.3 includes an implementation of the Filesystem library defined
>   by the technical specification ISO/IEC TS 18822:2015. Because this is
>   an experimental library extension, not part of the C++ standard, ***it is
>   implemented in a separate library, libstdc++fs.a, and there is no
>   shared library for it. To use the library you should include
>    and link with -lstdc++fs***. The library
>   implementation is incomplete on non-POSIX platforms, specifically
>   Windows support is rudimentary.
>
> Due to the experimental nature of the Filesystem library the usual
>   guarantees about ABI stability and backwards compatibility do not
>   apply to it. There is no guarantee that the components in any
>    header will remain compatible between different GCC
>   releases.

*(emphasis mine)*

To link `libstdc++fs` explicitly only under GCC, you can use the [relevant CMake variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html):

```
target_link_libraries(foo other_lib)
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL GNU)
    target_link_libraries(foo stdc++fs)
endif()
```

Or, in a bit fancier manner,

```
if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL GNU)
    set(CXX_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARIES stdc++fs)
else()
    set(CXX_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARIES)
endif()
target_link_libraries(foo other_lib ${CXX_FILESYSTEM_LIBRARIES})
```